# Adding antoher fields in TranslateBehavior in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, behavior, translate

I use TranslateBehavior in my app.
Model translate fields like name, content and slug. The table has many records.
...and now I must add antoher field to this table and I have problem. When I added field name to actsAs in model, my records return empty results. Why?

How add another field to Translated model after fact?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I suggest you try to clean the model cache (delete files from `path/to/project/app/tmp/cache/models`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

The solution was to execute a SQL query to create the new translated fields that should have been created before.

I had a title tarnslator field before. Now I want to add a company translated field.
My i18n table is translation.
My model is Speaker.

Here is the SQL query to execute:

```
INSERT INTO translation (locale, model, foreign_key, field)
    SELECT locale,model, foreign_key, 'company' FROM  translation
    WHERE model="Speaker" AND field="title";
```